# How to add label name to hoverlabel in Plotly parallel category plot?

Tags: python, formatting, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

[image]

I want to add the label name to the respective hoverlabels. Eg- The hoverlabel in the image that reads `%{label}` should instead read `Workplace Closing` and so on.

There is no `custom_data` or `text` property for parallel category plots. I tried using `meta` by passing it a list of all the labels (`meta=[dim[x]['label'] for x in range(len(dim))]`), but it displays the entire list on every hoverlabel rather than one element per hoverlabel. I also tried using `%{label}`, `%{labels}`, `%{dimension}` and some more to find any built in functionality, like you would use `%{x}` or `%{y}` in a plot with x and y arguments.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df =  {}
dim = []

for idx,var in enumerate(['country','School closing','Workplace closing','Cancel public events',
                      'Restrictions on gatherings','Close public transport','Stay at home requirements',
                      'Restrictions on internal movement','International travel controls',
                      'Public information campaigns']):
    df[var] = np.random.randint(4, size=4)
    dim.append(go.parcats.Dimension(values=df[var], label=var.title(), categoryorder='category ascending'))

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
fig = go.Figure(data = [go.Parcats(dimensions=[x for x in dim],
        line={'color': df.country})])
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate='%{label}')
```

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is because there is only one trace for all dimensions (using array of meta you get the whole list). You can use `%{category}` but not `%{dimension}`.. There are other variables available in hovertemplate, which correspond to the ones emitted as [event data](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-events/#event-data) by the front-end (like `%{fullData.name}`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about `%{category}`. Still trying to find the hoverlabel for labels though.